# Live USB won't install or try Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, uefi, live-usb

I kinda messed up big this time by trying to update my Ubuntu 14.04 version to 16.04. I tried a internal update via terminal using

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

That got stuck after an hour and I had to turn my laptop off. When I try to boot now I get into grub2 and everything there works fine. When I try to load Ubuntu I get

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Kodules
```

After that Ubuntu 16.04.3 starts and I get into tty1. The problem here is that my former login from 14.04 won't work. Dead end here and I'm switching to the Ubuntu Live USB.

This didn't go as smooth as I'd hoped, because I can reach the Ubuntu Live USB menu, but installing or trying Ubuntu gives me the error

```
Uncompression failed
System Halted
```

I've tried different ISO's (Ubuntu 16.04, 17.04, 17.10) and sometimes it gives  this error, sometimes just a black screen and sometimes the error:

```
[ 1.929082] kernel panic-not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0.0)
```

I've tried three live usb creators on my windows: Rufus, LinuxLive and Universal USB Installor. On Rufus I tried 'MBR Partition Scheme for BIOS or UEFI' and 'MBR Partition Scheme for UEFI'. In the BIOS of my laptop I tried all the Live USBs with 'UEFI Boot Support Enabled' and with 'UEFI Boot Support Disabled', which sometimes brought me slighty further in the process (to a menu) but never to a succesful install.

Kinda sure the problem lies at the laptop, not the USB or the images. I backed up my important data and the only thing I want at the moment is a proper working Ubuntu distribution. Can anyone help me here?

> Laptop Specs:
>
> - Samsung NP300V3a-S01NL
> - CPU Architecture: Intel Sandy Bridge
> - CPU Model: Intel Core i5-2410M
> - Motherboard chipset: Intel Mobile HM65
> - RAM: 4GB DDR3 (SODIMM)
> - GPU Technology: Nvidia Optimus
> - Dedicated GPU: Nvidia Geforce GT520M

Comment: Chances are your USB is corrupt or ISO was corrupt. You should try loading your current install in rescue mode.

Comment: Found the fix: I had a 2.0 usb which was connected to a 3.0 port. Probably that somehow corrupted my live usb

Comment: I presume you fixed it by using only 2.0 from computer with 2.0 usb flash drive?